# Android - How to set initial position of progressview of SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: android, progress, swiperefreshlayout

I have an Activity holding a SwipeRefreshLayout with a ListView inside.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
 android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">             
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I know I can use swipeView.setProgressViewOffset(false, start, end) to set position of progressview, but it only works when I drag on swipeView(it shows from start to end). 
If I use swipeView.setRefreshing(true), progressview keeps showing at its original position(not at start, but a position below top of swiperefreshlayout). So is there a way to work it out?

Comment: @Amrut Bidri what's the unclear point?

Comment: what you want to achieve is not clear